# Is it possible to compile an Android app by running Git Bash and ant commands from within a Java Program?

Tags: java, android, git, bash, ant

I have a project requirement to find a way to compile any number of customized apps in android from a program where the user inputs a code version, then selects from a list of customized apps that need to be built, then the user selects the option "Build". Upon selecting this option, the program will compile a signed APK file for each app selected.

The code for the app is on Bit Bucket, where we have 2 repositories: the first is for the core library code. This code is not customer dependent. whether we were building an app for company A or company B, this code would remain the same. At compile time it would be marked as a library and imported by the customized code. The second repository holds the customized code. This code has the specific UI theme for the customer.

My current strategy is to use Android ant and git bash from within a java program. I would write a program that would store the commit hash for both the library code and the customized code. When the user chooses to make a build, the program would use the stored commit hash numbers to pull the desired code from their respective repositories by running Git Bash commands from within the program. Next, the program would clean the project and make a signed build by running ant (a command line compiler for android) commands from within the program. Since it would be automated, the program could then loop through as many builds as it needs to. As the functionality of this depends entirely on the ability to run Git Bash and Ant commands from within a Java program, we return to the focus question: Is it possible to run Git Bash and Ant commands from a program?

Comment: i think ant is capable of handling git already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run any arbitrary console command using the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` methods on any normal computer. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html